# How to stop adding already added value from JCombobox to JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel

I am working on netbeans and creating a swing application. I have created a JComboBox and a JTable. I am able to add value from JComboBox to JTable on a button click but if I repeat the same process the same value is again again added to the table. How to stop adding the existed value of JComboBox.

This is the code of JComboBox

```
private void populateCombo(){
    organizationComboBox.removeAllItems();
    for (Organization.Type type : Organization.Type.values()){
            organizationComboBox.addItem(type);
    }
}
```

This is the code of JTable

```
private void populateTable(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) organizationTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);

    for (Organization organization : organizationDirectory.getOrganizationList()){
        Object[] row = new Object[2];
        row[0] = organization.getOrganizationID();
        row[1] = organization.getName();

        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

This is the code for my add button

```
Type type = (Type) organizationComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    Organization o = organizationDirectory.createOrganization(type);

        if(type.equals(Type.Receptionist)){
           o.getSupportedRole().add(new ReceptionistRole());
            }else
            if(type.equals(Type.Doctor)){
                    o.getSupportedRole().add(new DoctorRole());
                }else
                if(type.equals(Type.VaccineManager)){
                    o.getSupportedRole().add(new VaccineManagerRole());
                }else
                    if(type.equals(Type.LabAssistant)){
                    o.getSupportedRole().add(new LabAssistantRole());
                }else
                    if(type.equals(Type.Donor)){
                    o.getSupportedRole().add(new DonorRole());
                }else
                    if(type.equals(Type.Patient)){
                    o.getSupportedRole().add(new PatientRole());
                }

    populateTable();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use DefaultTableModel. This class is only for simple cases and demo applications. Simply look [here](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/?source=archives) for example of your own model.

So your model will looks like:

```
public class OrganizationModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    protected String[] columnNames;
    protected List<Organization> dataVector;

    public OrganizationModel(String[] columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        dataVector = new ArrayList<Organization>();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
       return columnNames[column];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return String.class;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return column == 0? dataVector.get(row).getOrganizationID() : dataVector.get(row).getName();
    }

    public void addRowWhenNotExist(Organization o) {
        if (!dataVector.contains(o)) {
            dataVector.add(o);
            fireTableRowsInserted(dataVector.size() - 1, dataVector.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For correct working of this example you also need correct definition of methods equals and hashCode for your class Organization.

```
public class Organization {

    // your stuff

    public boolean equals(Object another) {
        if (another instanceof Organization) {
           return getOrganizationID() == ((Organization) another).getOrganizationID();
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getOrganizationID();
    }
}
```

Comment: public abstract class Organization {
   private String name;
   private int organizationID;
    
   public enum Type{
        Admin("Admin Organization"), Receptionist("Receptionist Organization"),
        Doctor("Doctor Organization"),VaccineManager("Vaccine Manager Organization"),
        LabAssistant("LabAssistant Organization"),Donor("Donor Organization"),Patient("Patient Organization");
   
       private String value;
                private Type(String value) {
           this.value = value;
       }
       public String getValue() {
           return value;
       }
   }

Comment: no its not working.. is there any way to code in the combobox or table for this problem.?

Comment: Probably equals/hashCode is wrong implemented for your case. Try to implement it yourself. You can provide comparition using field Type or something else.